# How to redirect sqlpackage StdError stream through .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface, sqlpackage

I need to call `SqlPackage` from a C# .NET 7 application and I'm doing so by creating a `System.Diagnostics.Process`. My sample code can be found below.

I can run the command, however whenever I redirect stdError if there is no error in the command I am met with

> An unexpected failure occurred: The handle is invalid..

but if there is an error in the command, I will get the appropriate error message.

If I want to provide a *valid* command I have to remove StdError redirection in order for me the receive the contents of stdOutput.

Why am I getting an invalid handle error in the case *there is no error* redirected from stdError but it works fine when *there is an error* redirected to stdError? And if possible how can I get around this issue so that i can see both output and possible errors from the commandline.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"sqlpackage.exe", // Replace with your command or executable
    // Arguments = "/a:Import /tcs:\"Data Source=foo;Initial Catalog=bar;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd" /sf:backup.bacpac /p:DatabaseEdition=Premium /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=P4", // Invalid command to test stdError working with an invalid command
    Arguments = "/help", // Does not work if stdError is redirected
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

// Create and start the process
using var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = processStartInfo,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

// Set up a single event handler for both output and error streams
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgs.Data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Data);
        // You can log the output to a file or another logging mechanism here
    }
};

// Set up a single event handler for both output and error streams
process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgs.Data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Data);
        // You can log the output to a file or another logging mechanism here
    }
};

// Start the process and begin reading the output asynchronously
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

// Wait for the process to finish
process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("Process completed with exit code: " + process.ExitCode);
```

Comment: See following which give example of standard output.  Standard error should be handle in similar fashion with a streamreader.

Comment: @jdweng Did you forget to link the example?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Your process is writing an empty string to the error stream and that's the issue.

Set  `RedirectStandardError = false` and change your code like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"sqlpackage.exe", 
    Arguments = "/help", 
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

using var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = processStartInfo,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgs.Data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Data);
    }
};

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("Process completed with exit code: " + process.ExitCode);
```

Comment: But this would discard the errorstream entirely meaning that I would never see potential errors which isn't what I'm after.